# replace method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to remove the `width` and `height` attribute from the iframes and remove all newline characters from my input. So I made this:

```
var convert; 
$(".button1").click(function(){
  console.log("done");
  var convert = document.getElementById("convert").value;
  convert = convert.replace(/\r?\n/g, '');
  //convert = convert.replace("width=\'500\' height=\'294\'")
  convert= convert.replace("width=", '');
  convert = convert.replace("height=", '');
  convert= convert.replace("'500'", '');
  convert= convert.replace("'294'", '');
  console.log(convert);
})
```

But it has inconsistent outcome. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
I've tried the commented out part too, but that doesn't work either.

It always manages to remove the newlines and make the input a one-line string, but it never manages to wipe out all the `width` and `height` attributes from a big string like this:

```
<li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মোস্তফা কামালঃ-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uZuzPrQ9X_w?&theme=dark&autohide=2&fs=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মতিউর রহমান:-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u1thP64dhrk?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ নূর মোহাম্মদ:-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xjf6CO2bWW8?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মোহাম্মদ রুহুল আমিন :-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CpDdMNNkkck?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মুন্সী আবদুর রউফ:-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oUgsJSUHZlM?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ হামিদুর রহমান :-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/74hSM6rGwq4?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li> <li> <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ জাহাঙ্গীর :-</h1> <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ctVFVaAmG7w?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div> </li>
```

**The above code line is the input after removing the newlines.**

The actual HTML code with newlines is below:

```
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মোস্তফা কামালঃ-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uZuzPrQ9X_w?&theme=dark&autohide=2&fs=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মতিউর রহমান:-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u1thP64dhrk?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ নূর মোহাম্মদ:-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xjf6CO2bWW8?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মোহাম্মদ রুহুল আমিন :-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CpDdMNNkkck?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ মুন্সী আবদুর রউফ:-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oUgsJSUHZlM?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ হামিদুর রহমান :-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/74hSM6rGwq4?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
<li>
  <h1 class="liname">বীরশ্রেষ্ঠ জাহাঙ্গীর :-</h1>
  <div class="iframe"><iframe width='500' height='294' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ctVFVaAmG7w?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</li>
```

Comment: What is the `convert` do you mention here ?

document.getElementById("convert")

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Is the goal to actually remove the height & width from the iframes? Or is the goal to return the HTML of the iframes, but without height & width? For the former, you can use jQuery to do the heavy lifting by removing width & height attributes; for the latter you need .replace() or similar.

Comment: Use this instead to remove any whitespace between tags: `convert.replace(/>\s+</g,'><');`

Comment: my goal is to remove the height and width from the iframe and return that iframe as a string

Answer (score 0):

I do not what is your code about, but all you need to do is:

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
    $('iframe').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
 })
```

Comment: Or use JavaScript's native method [removeAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp).